# Delayed jQuery pulsate in combination with timers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing around with jQuery animations and timers in Javascript, and I would like to achieve having a small sentence on my page pulsate (i.e. change opacity from 1->0.2, 0.2->1) a few seconds after the page loads, pulsate for a few seconds, stop pulsating and change color from black to red.

```
<div class="pulsate">Test</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  var p = $(".pulsate");
  for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    p.animate({opacity: 0.2}, 1000, 'linear')
     .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, 'linear');
  }
});
</script>
```

I have my current work in the following JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/nLqmz/). Anyone have any thoughts about how I could approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works but there probably is a nicer way to do it:

```
$(function() {
var p = $(".pulsate"),
    faded = false,
    stopFading = false;
setTimeout(function(){
    toggleFade();
    setTimeout(function(){
        stopFading = true;  
        p.animate({'color': 'red', 'opacity' : 1},{'duration' : 'fast'});
    }, 3000);
}, 3000);

function toggleFade() {
    if (!stopFading) {
        p.animate({
            'opacity': faded ? 0.2 : 1
        },{
            'duration' : 500, 
            'complete' : function(){
                faded = faded ? false : true;
                toggleFade();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/nLqmz/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var p = $(".pulsate");
    var pulse = setTimeout(function () {
        pulsate();
    }, 3000);

    var = pulsate_repeat ;
    var pulsate = function() {
        p.animate({
            'color': 'red',
            'opacity': 1
        }, function () {
            p.animate({
            'color': 'black',
                'opacity': 0.2});
        });
        //pulsate();
        pulsate_repeat = setTimeout(function () {
            pulsate();
        }, 500);
    };

    //after 30 secs stop repeating
    setTimeout(function () {
        clearTimeout(pulsate_repeat);
    }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: This is really great. What would you need to add to terminate the pulsate animation after a certain length of time (e.g. after 30 seconds of pulsating, stop the pulsating)? Could you call .stop() on pulsate or is it a bit more involved?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just customize the `pulsate` class in CSS the way you want:

```
function pulsateElement(element){
    element.removeClass('pulsate');
    setTimeout(function(){
        element.addClass('pulsate');
        setTimeout(function(){
            pulsateElement(element);
        },500);
    },700);
}
```